# Get values of array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array like the following :

```
$arr = array('Test' => 'stuff');
```

Getting it like this :

```
$arr_keys = array_keys($arr);
```

Gives me the following schema :

```
array(0 => 'Test');
```

Now I want to remove the keys on that array, but doing this doesn't work :

```
array_values($arr_keys)
```

This gives me the same `key => value` array, how to remove the keys and only get the desired result which is :

```
array('Test');
```

Comment: Those are not exactly keys that you are thinking of.  They are just indexes of the array.

Comment: `array(0 => 'Test');` and `array('Test');` are the same thing, every array has a key even if it's a numeric index.

Comment: You cannot - int index are default - you may want to use `SET` and not array (array element has to have keys)

Comment: @GiveMeFreedomOrGiveMeFire `json_encode($arr_keys)` can return `["Test"]` though. It's just a different format of printing an array. PHP will show its index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result of `array(0 => 'Test');` is exactly the desired output you expect to get. All array-elements **must** have a unique index to it - and if you don't provide one, PHP will create one for you.

When you do

```
$array = array('Test');
```

You create an array with a singular element in it - but since you did not specify a key to this value, it will be auto-generated by PHP, numerically starting from zero. You can verify this by doing

```
print_r($array);
```

..which will yield the same result as your `$arr_keys = array_keys($arr);`

See this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/VD2ra).